# mysql NOW() with defined time

Tags: mysql

I need to perform a mysql select query where date time field in table is less then todays date with a time of 2am.

How would I structure this

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE datetimefield < (DATE(NOW()) and time 2am)
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE datetimefield < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36e51/2) - in the fiddle I used a hard coded date '2013-05-04', so it would work correctly later.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE datetimefield < STR_TO_DATE(concat(curdate(), ' ', '02'),'%Y-%m-%d %H')

Comment: Going from date to string back to date is a little hinky.